# how to encrypt decrept public key

Tags: android

this is my login page code below and i also find a RSA PUBLIC PRIVITE KEY on google how do i  insert this code in my code? can anyone help me i found rsa code formthis url http://xtrace.blogspot.com/search/label/RSA

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.agapplogin);

    TextView lblMobileNo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblMobileNo);
    lblMobileNo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_red));

    mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNo);

    TextView lblPinNo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblPinNo);
    lblPinNo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_red));

    pin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPinNo);

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {                
             postLoginData();
         }
         });      

                ;}  

public void postLoginData() 

   {
             Intent i = new   
   Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),new.class);
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("mno", mobile.getText().toString());
             bundle.putString("pinno", pin.getText().toString());
             i.putExtras(bundle);
             startActivity(i);          }
}


            ///this is RSA code which i found





   import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
   import java.math.BigInteger;
   import java.security.Key;
   import java.security.KeyFactory;
   import java.security.KeyPair;
   import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
   import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

        /**
        * This class generates key pair and saves in file in current directory
       * 
       * @author amit
       * 
       */
        public class RSAKeyGenerator {

public void generateKeyPair(String publicKeyFileName,
        String privateKeyFileName) {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
    try {
        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    try {
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,
                RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(privateKey,
                RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

        saveToFile(publicKeyFileName, pub.getModulus(),
                pub.getPublicExponent());
        System.out.println("public key saved");
        saveToFile(privateKeyFileName, priv.getModulus(),
                priv.getPrivateExponent());
        System.out.println("private key saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error ");
    }
}

private void saveToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp)
        throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
    try {
        oout.writeObject(mod);
        oout.writeObject(exp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected error", e);
    } finally {
        oout.close();
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RSAKeyGenerator t = new RSAKeyGenerator();
    t.generateKeyPair("public.key", "private.key");

}

        }








        import javax.crypto.Cipher;

         public class RSAEncDec {

private PublicKey readPublicKeyFromFile(String fileloc) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(fileloc));

    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            in));
    try {
        BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return pubKey;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    } finally {
        oin.close();
    }
}

private PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String fileLoc)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLoc));

    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            in));
    try {
        BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey prvKey = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        return prvKey;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    } finally {
        oin.close();
    }
}

public byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] data, String fileLoc) {
    try {
        PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(fileLoc);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return cipherData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("some thing went wrong");
    }
    return null;
}

public byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] data, String fileLoc) {
    try {
        PrivateKey pubKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile(fileLoc);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return cipherData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("some thing went wrong");
    }
    return null;
}

/*
 * string
 * 
 * @param data (normal string)
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String encrypt(String data, String fileLoc) {
    byte[] enc = rsaEncrypt(data.getBytes(), fileLoc);
    return Base64.encode(enc);
}

/**
 * return the normal string
 * 
 * @param data
 *            (base64 encoded string)
 * @return
 * @throws Base64DecodingException
 */
public String decrypt(String data, String fileLoc)
        throws Base64DecodingException {
    byte[] enc = Base64.decode(data);
    byte[] decryptedData = rsaDecrypt(enc, fileLoc);
    return new String(decryptedData);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RSAEncDec obj = new RSAEncDec();
    String enc = obj.encrypt("hello world", "./public.key");
    System.out.println(enc);
    String dat = null;
    try {
        dat = obj.decrypt(enc, "./private.key");
    } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(dat);

        }

       }
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do exactly?

Do you want to use RSA to encrypt the mobileNo and pin before sending it to the server?

If this the case, you might want to generate a key pair at your server and *only* make the public key accessible to your android.

The code above generates both private and public key in Android which I do not think what you want to do here.

Check this article to learn how to generate the keys in your server and use them in Android
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/rsa-string-encryption-security